# Node.js TCP Socket does not write to connection from module

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp, server

I have a TCP server with multiple clients connected. An array with all connections stored in different module. Like this:

```
// connections.js

let connections = [];

module.exports.addConnection = (connection) => {connections.push(connection);}
module.exports.getConnectionByID = (ID) => {
 for(const connection of connections) {if (connection.id == ID) return connection;}
}
```

```
// app.js

const connections = require(./connections.js);

const net = require('net');
const server = net.createServer();

server.listen(9000, () => {});

// Connection -----------------

server.on('connection', (connection) => {
    connection.id = getSomeRandomID();

    connections.addConnection(connection);

    connection.on('data', (buffer) => {
        const messageTo = connections.getConnectionByID(data.messageTo);
        messageTo.write(data.message);
    });

});
```

Some code was removed to make it clear.

`getConnectionByID` returns valid Socket object, by the way, so there is no issue there. 
`connection.write` returns `true`.

The problem here is that message does not gets send. But if I send to message to current connection using `connection` variable, than it gets away successully. My guess is that `getConnectionByID` returns a copy of real connection, not a reference. But as far as I know, JS do not copy objects values, it uses references.

But why does messange don't get send to other client?

Comment: Maybe you are missing a equals `if (connection.id = ID)` use `if (connection.id === ID)`

Comment: No, it is okay. I just missed it in question.